# Parse: How to prevent pointers from being saved recursively in Android?

Tags: android, pointers, recursion, parse-platform

I a parse class called `Booking` which has pointers to Parse classes: `Ticket`and `_User` and other irrelevant fields.
Where `Ticket` has pointers to `Location` and more irrelevant fields.
Most classes other than the `Booking` class has Class level Access List Restrictions, which is necessary for the security of my app.
The following is the code I use to attempt to save a booking object using the android SDK:

```
    final Booking booking = new Booking();
    // For pointer like behaviour
    Ticket ticketPointer = Ticket.createWithoutData(Ticket.class, bookingData.getTicket().getObjectId());
    booking.setTicket(ticketPointer);

    ArrayList<Coupon> couponPointers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Coupon coupon : bookingData.getCoupons()) {
        // For pointer like behaviour
        couponPointers.add(Coupon.createWithoutData(Coupon.class, coupon.getObjectId()));
    }
    booking.setCoupons(couponPointers);

    booking.setClient(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    booking.setTicketCount(bookingData.getTicketCount());
    booking.setPaymentMethod(Booking.PaymentMethod.CASH_ON_ARRIVAL);

    booking.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (asserter.assertPointerQuietly(e)) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } else {
                l.d("Successfully posted a booking request on server");
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is that parse saves object recursively, so even objects pointed to by the pointers are saved along with the object being saved. And since the other classes can't be accessed by regular users, exceptions are raised when attempts to save these objects pointed to by the pointers are made. So, I put the ticket and coupon objects into the booking object in the form of pointers using the `createWithoutData` method as marked in comments as `// For pointer like behaviour` as per the solution to saving pointers [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-save-pointer-in-object).
All this works well, and I got rid of exceptions raised by accessing the Ticket and the Coupon class which were saved recursively.
However, to my surprise, the above code results in another exception caused by an attempt to access the `Location` class which is pointed to by the pointer of the `Ticket` object which is pointed to by the `Booking` object(2nd level pointer)!!!.

Is there any way to prevent the location object from being pointed to? An ideal solution would be to disable recursive saves in the first place, but any solution would be appreciated.

A workarounds exist, but it is ugly, and I would like to avoid it: It involves using a string representation of the object id of the object instead of the pointer.

Comment: Parse will only save changes in related objects that have unsaved changes.  If a particular user cannot write an object, then that user shouldn't change that object in memory.   So for example, in the case above, the question you should ask is, why is a location object being created or changed when a booking is created?  Usually the domain of travel, locations are known in advanced an not-writable by users.

Comment: @danh You have made a very good point, but the reason the location object has probably been modified in memory is because these objects have been serialized and deserialized as they were being passed from one activity to the other as per the solution [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/passing-around-parseobjects-in-android) .i.e. the modifications are unintentional.  
But I still don't understand how the location is being saved recursively, since the `Ticket` object itself is being put without its data and so shouldn't contain a reference to the `Location` object in the first place!

Comment: I don't know enough about android to say for sure, but maybe that solution for passing objects led you astray.  Also, there isn't strong evidence presented in the question that the permissions issue on a location object is caused by saving the new booking.  I suggest you reduce this to an MRE by saving the ticket on the line after you create it.  Then try saving the booking on the line after that, etc.

Comment: @danh I doubt it, since I have not made any saves of any objects other than a booking object anywhere in the project. Moreover, I am not receiving individual exceptions, instead, I am receiving a multi-exception in response to a single request.